# Supply-independent current source

Tags: transistors, mosfet, circuit-analysis, analog, current-source

In the given circuit, the resistor defines the current and it is connected at the source of M2 in this circuit. What will happen if it is connected to the source of M1?

I don't see any problem, but I saw on the internet that we should not connect the resistor to M1. Could anyone help me understand the issue in this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We start by assuming that all transistors are in saturation (i.e. square-law) and that \$K>1\$, and then make a couple of observations:

- M3 and M4 are paired up as a current mirror with equal dimensions, meaning that their respective branches carry the same current (with a small discrepancy due to channel length modulation).
- M2 is \$K\$ times wider than M1, so it needs a smaller \$V_{GS}\$ to carry the same current.

If we wanted an analytical approximation, we could apply square-law with the currents equated (\$V_{Gn}\$ denotes the common nFET gate voltage). As an approximation neglecting channel-length modulation:

$$I = a\frac{W}{L}\left(V_{Gn}-V_{th}\right)^2 = Ka\frac{W}{L}\left(V_{Gn}-V_{th} - IR\right)^2$$

If so inclined, you could solve this analytically to get a closed-form expression for the current in the given circuit, assuming \$K>1\$. However, the question and bounty message ask that an intuitive explanation be given instead.

The key here is that M2 has the wider aspect ratio, so its Vgs should be smaller than M1's for the same current. If we placed the resistor on M1 instead, then M1's high gate voltage would turn M2 on very hard, turning M3/M4 on even harder and hence driving M1 even more. Such a system would quickly violate our assumption with all four transistors entering triode (confirmed with a simulation).

Comment: Could u explain more on how the transistor M2 gets into triode region id Rs is placed at M1? Thank you

Comment: @prashanth M1 is diode connected so its gate voltage will be IrefR+Vgs; this overdrives M2 to a huge current which is copied over the PMOS pair and drives M1 even harder.

Comment: Thanks. got some idea :)

Comment: I just realized that the circuit is in positive feedback. So, will it be unstable if there is no resistor?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a resistor to both sources of M1 & M2, but that would just add to the RdsOn and when equal would be in saturation both conducting the same current if K=1.

But by adding resistance to M2-S  the currents are still almost equal but by increasing M2's Rs, the currents drop rapidly with the reduction of M1's Vgs=Vds and its current source mirrored by M3.

By adding a greater resistance to M1-S, than M2-S, forces Vgs up on  M2 into a higher RdsOn and starts to increase M2's current and make it very unbalanced and unstable.